# Проблема в PhpMyAdmin!

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, vesta, control-panel

Установил себе **vesta cp** и написал сайт на php, код точно верный но **в бд таблицы не созаются и не записыаются данные,** попробовал скачать xxamp и запустить то же самоес локалки, и все заработало, и проблема в phpmyadmin, на сервере, подскажие пожалуйста что мне сделать можно попробовать?
Вот у меня еще на серверев phpmyadmin есть такая надпись как ошибка:"**Ошибка при указании соединения для controluser в конфигурации.**" Может из за нее потому что на локалке такой надписи нет. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: А какое отношение phpmyadmin имеет к вашему коду на php и к созданию таблиц в базе данных ? А текст ошибки phpmyadmin явно указывает что в его конфигурационном файле вы неверно указали параметры для подключения к базе данных. (и может вы и в своих php скриптах указали неверное подключение к БД ?)

Comment: P.S. Обратите внимание phpmyadmin это лишь средне удобный прользовательский интерфейс для работы с базой данной mysql, написанный на php. Он не влияет ни на работу самой базы данных mysql, ни тем более на другие программы, написанные на php или других языках

Comment: значит дело в vesta cp?

Comment: нет я все правильно написал

Comment: Я не знаю что такое vesta cp. Судя по тому что это некая панель управления, могу предположить что при установке ее к вам, она сама правильно настроила все во всех конфигурационных файлах. А на хостинге могла этого не сделать или вы ее там не разворачивали. Учитесь писать сами все настройки во всех конфигурационных файлах, что бы не зависеть от разных сомнительных "панелей управления"

Comment: Это я к тому, что на основе данной вами информации можно сказать только, что в конфигурационном файле phpmyadmin что то неверно указано. А что там не так сказать невозможно, потому что надо знать ваши параметры подключения к БД (который вам должен был дать хостер) и видеть собственно сам конфиг

Comment: да уж. Vesta cp это панель управления сервером

Comment: Сначала надо учиться настраивать сервера руками, без панелей управления. А панели управления начинать использовать потом, для удобства, точно понимая что и в какой ситуации она делает. Тогда у вас не будет сюрпризов при переносе сайта на другой хостинг. Что до меня, то да, я ненавижу панели управления, ибо они вечно делают что нибудь не то, что мне нужно. Руками в конфигах надежнее и быстрее и если что то идет не так точно знаешь где и что править

Answer (score 0):

проверь префикс базы данных, имя пользователя пароль в mysql. Скорее всего у тебя в mysql на хостинге не существует пользователя которому надо дать права к доступу бд.